# Xcode 8 Firebase Error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having a bit of issue implying my code. I'm trying to build a chat app and I'm getting one lousy error. I was wondering if anyone could help me fix it or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    if nameField?.text != "" { // 1
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously(completion: { (user, error) in // 2
    if let err = error { // 3
    print(err.localizedDescription)
    return
    }

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToChat", sender: nil) // 4
    })
    }

}
```

[image: Picture Here also]

Comment: did my answer helped?

Comment: if answer helped then please accept it. Else I have other solutions as well

Answer (score 0):

I think as textfield outlet is always optional, so you are getting this error.Take value of textfield in variable then compare it. Let say code as below:

```
let stringTextValue = nameField.text! as String

if stringTextValue != "" {
```